# Stripe iframe for 3d secure authentication doesn't show up on android chrome browser

Tags: reactjs, iframe, stripe-payments

I am refactoring an e-commerce web application, I am using react (with Nextjs). My implementation is pretty simple and similar to what I have previously but I have a big problem with the fact that payments which need 3d secure authentication do not trigger the iframe ONLY on mobile and ONLY on some browsers (chrome, brave, ecosia but OK on firefox) on after calling the confirmCardPayment function  :

```
        res = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
          receipt_email: customerData.email,
          payment_method: {
            card,
            billing_details: billingDetails,
          },
        });
```

I can go through the 3d secure auth process + payment without any problem on computer or on firefox on mobile : my payment intent status is "requires_action" in all cases, the only difference is that on computer the iframe / pop-up show up, but not in the problematic cases.

So my guess is that it is browser specific, I tried to remove the custom style that I put on cardElement without any success, changed stripe and react-stripe versions to previous ones.

Does someone have any clue to address this issue ?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome mobile is in Stripe's [supported browsers](https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/supported_browsers) list, so the 3DS authentication flow should work in Chrome mobile browser.

Is there a public URL where I can visit and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thank you for you response!
Yes you can visit https://osdivae-v3-git-develop-brian-charles-development.vercel.app/ , add a product to cart and go to checkout, give some random values in checkout and at payment page give 4000 0000 0000 3220 card which force 3D secure.
Try on chrome android to see the "not loading iframe".
When debugging with usb cable my mobile browser, I saw that changes in userAgent may have an effect on the problem.

Comment: For further information I noticed that the authenticate3DS2 call in stripe controller code does not trigger and so the authenticate network call is note done.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just tested your website in a Chrome mobile browser and I'm able to launch the 3DS dialog and complete the payment.

Are there any specific steps that I need to take to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Okay so it does not seem to be only related to browser.
I got the problem on two different mobiles (and on these phones not on firefox). I could ask to other people if they can test it out to check if it is only on my side.
I havn't some specific steps to reproduce the same error that there is on these two phones, I'll tell you about the other tests.
Do you think it is possible that it is related with the device used ? The two mobiles are something like 4 or 5 years old.

Comment: Replacing the default user agent
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36'
by
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Firefox/117.0 Mobile Safari/537.36' 
allow me to show the iframe. This is incredible...
Maybe problem due to my device + chrome...